# Tutles and stuff: how do i make a border for turtles?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have a turtle named t and a turtle named to, turtle named t is already resolved as if turtle t touches the border (which was drawn by turtle named d, it will print game over and stuff, but i also need for turtle to, which is a turtle that moves randomly, to always move inside the box drawn by turtle d

i have this code:

```
from time import sleep
import turtle
import random

s = turtle.Screen()
s.bgcolor('white')
s.setup(500,380)

d=turtle.Turtle()
d.penup()
d.goto(-150,-150)
d.pensize(5)
d.pendown()
d.hideturtle()
for x in range(4):
  d.forward(300) 
  d.left(90) 

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.shape('turtle')
t.color('blue')
t.penup()
to = turtle.Turtle()
to.shape('turtle')
to.color('black')
to.penup()


for peepee in range(1, 6):
    xcor=[]
    ycor=[]
    xrandomlist=[]
    yrandomlist=[]
    if peepee==5:
      print("ur now on the final level")
    else:
      print(f"u r playing level {peepee}.")

    t.goto(40,-40)

  
    to.goto(40,40)
    t.setheading(180)
    to.setheading(180)
    to.speed(peepee)

    def left():
      t.left(90)

    def right():
      t.left(-90)

    def goup():
      t.forward(15)
      xcor.append(t.xcor())
      ycor.append(t.ycor())
    def godown():
      t.forward(-15)
      xcor.append(t.xcor())
      ycor.append(t.ycor()) 
      
    def skadaddle():
      if to.distance(t) < 120:
        to.setheading(to.towards(t) + 180)
      to.forward(30)


    def drunkt():
      turn=random.choice([90,-90])
      to.left(turn)
      go=random.choice([-20, 20])
      def yoyo():
        to.forward(go)
        xrandomlist.append(to.xcor())
        yrandomlist.append(to.ycor())
      yoyo()
      skadaddle()
      
    s.onkeypress(left, "Left")
    s.onkeypress(right, "Right")
    s.onkeypress(goup, "Up")
    s.onkeypress(godown, "Down")
    s.listen()

    while True:
      drunkt()
      skadaddle() 
      if t.xcor()>130 or t.xcor()<-130:
        print("game over")
        s.bye()
        sleep(9999)
      if t.ycor()>130 or t.ycor()<-130:
        print("game over")
        s.bye()
        sleep(9999)
      if t.distance(to)<50:
        print(' ')
        print("noice")
        print(' ')
        for x in range(len(xcor)):
          t.speed(1)
          t.goto(xcor[-1],ycor[-1])
          xcor.pop(-1)
          ycor.pop(-1)

        for x in range(len(xrandomlist)):
          to.speed(1)
          to.goto(xrandomlist[-1],yrandomlist[-1])
          xrandomlist.pop(-1)
          yrandomlist.pop(-1)
        sleep(2)
        break

turtle.done()
s.bye()
```

Comment: What do you like to happen, if the random walk turtle to is walking out of the box? Should it stay at the edge or should it "bounce" of?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).